# How do i get my macro to transpose data that is a string and number

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro to transpose data that is horizontal into vertical :

```
Set Rng = Range("A1:D10")
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("g1").Select
k = 0

For Each rw In Rng.Rows
    For Each mycell In rw.Columns
        If IsEmpty(mycell) Then Exit For

        If mycell.Column = 1 Then
            myletter = mycell
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=k, columnOffset:=0) = myletter
            ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=k, columnOffset:=1) = mycell
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The macro works great except that when it is run, it tranposes the data but if the data is stored as text then it chops it and converts it to a number, is there any way to amend the macro and get it to not do this?

example : If i had `00293472427` the macro spits out `293472427`

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Forgot to say, before transposing my data looks like this :

```
A 22.2 11 14 21
```

And after it looks like this :

```
A 22.2
A 11
A 14
A 21
```

Comment: You might consider to use the transpose function from vba:  `Application.Transpose(myRange)`

Comment: How would i encorporate this into my macro? Apologies i am very new to Macros and VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me that you want to make a copy of the cells.

```
For Each rw In Rng.Rows
For Each mycell In rw.Columns
    If IsEmpty(mycell) Then Exit For

    If mycell.Column = 1 Then
      Set myletter = mycell
    Else
       myletter.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=k, columnOffset:=0)
       mycell.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=k, columnOffset:=1)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next
Next
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for, thanks very much for this it saves a lot of my time!

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure where you want to `Transpose` your result, but in order to keep the numeric value you have, which is stored as a `String` (since it's keeping the `00` as a prefix) use the code below:

```
myletter = mycell.Value2 ' get the Value2 (without the cell format)

With mycell.Offset(1, 1)
    .NumberFormat = "@" ' first: format the destination cell as text
    .Value2 = myletter ' second: get the Value2 (just in case)
End With
```

Comment: @GrandeurH can you specify from which cells (origina) to which cells (destination) you want to Transpose ?

Comment: Of course, the data to be transposed is in the range A1:D10

Comment: the location for which the data is to be transposed to is column H, my range is A-D as my data looks like this : A 22.2 34 56 56

Answer (score 0):

These are two ways to use Transpose:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeWithCopyAndPaste()

    Range("A1:D10").Copy
    Range("E10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Sub TransposeWithApplicaitonTranspose()

    Dim rngRange As Range
    Set rngRange = Range("A1:D10")
    Range("G20:P23").Cells = Application.Transpose(rngRange)

End Sub
```

The first one uses the Copy and Paste transpose from the Excel formulas, the second uses `Application.Transpose(Range)` as in the comments.